# Verificar vizinho em uma matriz

Tags: python, array, matriz

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Eu tenho uma matriz grande [10x10 por exemplo]
Ela possui valores de 1 a 9.

Devo verificar se um vetor [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (por exemplo) está contido nessa matriz.
Ao achar o primeiro numero do vetor dentro da matriz, eu devo verificar os vizinhos. Mas, se o numero 1 estiver no meio da matriz, eu tenho que verificar o entorno de 8 numeros.
Como eu faço essa leitura? 
Por gentileza, se alguém conseguir me explicar, tem como tentar fazer da forma mais "boba" possivel, usando while?

As funções abaixo não estão completas:

```
def ProcuraPrimeiroNumero(retang, padrao, i, j):
    '''Esta função procura o primeiro numero na matriz'''


    while i<num_lin: #procurando o 1º numero a partir da primeira linha
        while j<num_col: #procurando o 1º numero a partir da primeira coluna
            if retang[i][j] == padrao[0]: #Se o primeiro numero do vetor for igual ao primeiro numero da matriz
                VerificaSeCabe (retang, t, direçao, i, j)
                if VerificaSeCabe == 1:

def VerificaSeCabe(retang, direçao, t, i, j):
    k = 1
    l = 1
    aux_mat =[]
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while x<num_lin:
        lin = []
        y = 0
        while y<num_col:
            lin=lin+[0]
            y=y+1
        aux_mat = aux_mat +[lin]
        x=x+1
    while k<=4: #contador para as direções
        while l<=4: #contador para as direções
            if ((x+t-1)<=i-x):
                if (y+t-1<=j-1):
                    cabe = 1
                else:
                    cabe = -1
```

Comment: Como você está representando essa matriz no Python?

Comment: Esse é um trabalho de faculdade.
Eu leio a matriz de um arquivo txt.
Depois de ler, faço a contagem do numero de linhas e colunas.

Mas o "grosso" do algoritmo está nessa parte, de fazer a "varredura" ao redor de uma coordenada

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que já tem?

Comment: Vou tentar fazer isso.

Comment: Pode definir melhor o que seria "contido na matriz"? Você deve buscar apenas nas linhas da matriz ou vale ele estar nas colunas e diagonais?

Comment: Isso. Eu devo "verificar" todas linhas, colunas e diagonais. Como se fosse verificar no sentido horário: pra cima, diagonal, direita, diagonal, baixo, diagonal, esquerda, diagonal (conseguiu entender?)

Comment: Porém, o meu problema, é que estou conseguindo apenas verificar os pontos acima, diagonal, direita, diagonal e abaixo. O lado "esquerdo" não estou conseguindo verificar